# Perl - en / em dash in command line arguments

Tags: perl, parsing, arguments

I'm having a problem with my perl script with parsing command line arguments. Mainly, I'd like perl to parse argument preceding with (em/en)-dash as well as hypen. Consider the following command execution:

```
my_spript.pl -firstParam someValue –secondParam someValue2
```

As you can see, firstParam is prefixed with hypen and there is no problem with perl parsing it, but the secondParam is prefixed with en-dash and unfortunately Perl cannot recognize it as an argument.
I am using GetOptions() to parse arguments:

```
GetOptions(
    "firstParam" => \$firstParam,
    "secondParam" => \$secondParam
)
```

Comment: What module do you use? [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long)?

Comment: @choroba, Yes. I do use Getopt::Long

Comment: With all due respect, this is a crazy requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long), you can preprocess the arguments before giving them to `GetOptions`:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Getopt::Long;

s/^\xe2\x80\x93/-/ for @ARGV;

GetOptions('firstParam:s'  => \ my $first_param,
           'secondParam:s' => \ my $second_param);
print "$first_param, $second_param\n";
```

It might be cleaner to first decode the arguments, though:

```
use Encode;

$_ = decode('UTF-8', $_), s/^\N{U+2013}/-/ for @ARGV;
```

To work in different locale setting, use [Encode::Locale](http://p3rl.org/Encode::Locale):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Encode::Locale;
use Encode;
use Getopt::Long;

$_ = decode(locale => $_), s/^\N{U+2013}/-/ for @ARGV;

GetOptions('firstParam:s'  => \ my $first_param,
           'secondParam:s' => \ my $second_param);
print "$first_param, $second_param\n";
```

Comment: it is fine on OS-X, but doesn't seem to work on Windows. (perl version: 5.14.2). Do you have any idea what might be wrong ?

Comment: On Windows, the terminal encoding is probably not UTF-8. Specify the correct encoding.